# What is the term for words like “Look” and “Listen” followed by a comma at the start of a sentence?

Tags: terminology

What is the technical term for the part of speech in bold?

> **Look**, I'm not sure what you've been told, but carrots don't glow in the dark unless they mean business.

or

> **Listen**, the only thing keeping him alive right now is that carrot.

I want to find some information on this kind of word for a class I am teaching. I want to find more examples and instances of usage.

The problem is that I'm finding it impossible to come up with a search term that correctly encompasses it. I'm sure if I knew the technical word I could find more information myself, but just searching with "look" and "listen" is hopeless, because they are such common words.

From what I have been able to ascertain so far, the answer appears to fall somwehere between the camps of *interjection* and *discourse marker*, but not into either exclusively or perfectly.

Anything to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, I need to know the technical term so that *I* can search effectively for explanations and usage examples. I will then use these to craft an explanation that is easy for the students to understand. I am *not* looking to use the technical vocabulary to explain things directly to students.

**SOLUTION(?)**

Not sure enough to post it as an answer, but it may help others with a similar problem to know that term **attention-getting device** seems to be used a fair amount. Here are some interesting (though slightly tangential) resources I found:

- [Imperatives of visual versus auditory perception as pragmatic markers in English and Dutch](http://benjamins.com/series/etc/3-1/art/05van.pdf)
- [Links between Eyebrow Movements and Voice Variations : an Experimental
  Investigation](http://aune.lpl.univ-aix.fr/~fulltext/2461.pdf)
- [Discourse Markers in Native And Non-native English Discourse](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=WWMpdHUhQ_QC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=discourse%20markers%20look%20and%20listen&source=bl&ots=jAtdY0ICZ-&sig=IgFoZzX__WiwQNb-JKduklt9cU0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kI6AUazTFsHUkwXIsYCwBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=attention-getting%20devices&f=false)

Also found some good information here which helped me form my teaching plan, though again not precisely what I was looking for:

- [As I Was Saying: How and Why to Teach Discourse Markers](http://busyteacher.org/10076-how-and-why-to-teach-discourse-markers.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These words (**Look, Listen**) are imperatives used as *interjections*. You can replace them with **Hey!** or **Gosh!** or **Cowabunga, Buffalo Bob!**, or other exclamations, and the effect is  essentially the same: *Pay attention to what I'm saying!*

[**EDITED**]: Using the term *[discourse marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker)* is probably pointless because it's quite technical and doesn't help people understand why **Look** and **Listen** are used or how they function in those sentences. It also doesn't help EFL students speak better English. 
Terms like *imperative*, *interjection*, and *exclamation* are standard fare in their secondary school and university English classes and textbooks. I think that they don't need more than those to talk about these words and their function. The point, IMHO, is to teach them how to use the language, not to teach them how to talk about it, unless, of course, you're teaching a linguistics course. But in that case, I think you'd be a professional linguist yourself and wouldn't need to ask this question.

My experience in EFL classes in Japan (10 years) and Taiwan (17 years) has been that students want to learn "**useful**" English (whatever they think that means) and because they're taught English grammar rules from primary school on, they ask for technical grammatical information: they seem to believe that knowing the terms and the rules will help them, but this is patently false, as anyone who's lived and worked in both those countries knows.

Comment: +1 just for *Cowabunga, Buffalo Bob*...

Comment: _Discourse marker_ is no more vague than _adverb_; and there is a precise definition and tests that can be applied. _Interjection_ explains precisely nothing.

Comment: @JohnL: For a professional linguist _[discourse marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker)_ has a precise definition, but for other than linguistics students, I'd say the term is meaningless. Yes, _adverb_ is a [garbage-can term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb): "Some would go so far as to call adverbs a 'catch-all' category that includes all words that do not belong to one of the other parts of speech". Although it's not explanatory, _interjection_ & examples thereof are standard fare in ESL/EFL & native-speaker English classes. New terms merely add new terms.

Comment: The OP seems to be a computer programmer teaching EFL in Japan. I spent 10 years doing that right after getting my MA in theoretical Linguistics & had never heard the term. Japanese students might want to know esoteric grammatical terms, but to what end? That knowledge might make one a more competent linguist but not a more competent user of English. We need a basic lexicon of linguistic terms (verb, noun, subject, object, etc) to teach EFL, but not arcana. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Pragmatic marker subclass attention grabber / focusser

Comment: @Edwin: **I like that "attention grabber" term**. It states an understandable function. "Focusser" doesn't do it for me in this context because the focus of the sentence is usually the subject of the topic sentence or else it's some other fronted word or phrase, eg, _As far as carrots glowing in the dark,..._ or _As for what you've been told (about carrots glowing in the dark),..._.

Comment: @Bill: Yes; it's focus in the sense of focusing the attention of the audience on the meat of what is being said (and usually precedes it, for obvious reasons). 'Attention grabber' would be solely introductory (from _Hear ye ..._ to a phone chime!); 'Focusser' would include re-directions (like 'Moving on'; 'To change the subject...'). They're speaker - listener conversation 'lubricators', but the redirections also have a discourse-formatting function.

Comment: @Edwin: I see. Once it's defined, it's easier to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Bill Sorry, there seems to have been a severe misunderstanding here. I would never in a million years dream of using a technical term like "discourse marker" to explain something to ordinary *students*. I merely needed to know the technical terms so *I* could search more effectively for usage examples and explanations online. Although I like this answer, it still didn't solve my problem; despite refining my searches, I cannot find any specific examples of the usage I described. I know the fault must be with my search, because this is not an obscure usage. So... still need help :-/

Comment: @DavidJ: The fault may not be with your search. It may just be that there aren't any good examples & explanations online. Wikipedia has a very brief article on _[discourse particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_particle)_ that almost fits your need, but the operative particles there are _well_ & _like_, not _look_ or _listen_. Even the morbidly obese comprehensive grammars of English fall short despite their plethoras of examples. I rarely find one that matches what puzzles me. Maybe a linguist has written an article on what you're looking for; maybe not.

Comment: There's a book that you **might** find in good university library in Japan: _[Discourse Markers (Studies in Interactional Sociolinguistics)](http://snurl.com/26ybuua)_ Deborah Schiffrin (1988; Cambridge U Press). In fact, [two libraries](http://www.worldcat.org/title/discourse-markers/oclc/243527510) have it.

Comment: @Bill You may be right. I don't normally suck this badly at googling, so maybe the issue is not with me. I guess the information that there may be no answer is in and of itself a kind of answer, so I'll go with that :-)

Comment: LOL... Google is now showing this question as the first result when I continue to try and search. Oh, well....

Comment: @Bill For some reason I didn't notice your last comment before. I checked out the book and it did have some excellent information, including on both `look` and `listen`, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They are both discourse markers. There are almost no specific articles about their use as discourse markers in English, but they are listed often in more generic works on discourse markers. Their function as discourse markers is usually identified as "attention getters".
One of the few articles written about "look", is: 'From matrix clause to pragmatic marker - The history of look-forms', by Laurel J. Brinton in Journal of Historical Pragmatics 2:2. 2001. (pp. 177–199). 
Another function "look" can have, is to introduce reported speech. 
There is an article by Susan Blackwell (I don't remember the title, but you can find it in Google Books) who identifies this function.