# Why do we say "Look,..." when it means pay attention (listen) to what I'm about to say?

Tags: expressions

I've been reading through some questions trying to understand the usage of "Look, ..." before sharing important information. I have discovered this word placement can be considered an [interjection or attention getter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112846/what-is-the-term-for-words-like-look-and-listen-followed-by-a-comma-at-the-s).

In my experience, when I say or hear something prefaced by "Look," it is intended to convey the listener needs focus on or bring their attention to what is said next.

I have been reflecting on this usage and was curious on the etymology or origin of using "Look" to mean "listen" or pay attention. I wonder if this may have originated from in person conversations as a means to have people make eye contact or literally "look" at the speaker.

My spouse was curious if I spoke this way because I was raised in the Southern U.S.; however, I have noticed this usage in Spanish language as well.

Comment: In my experience, "Look" at the beginning of a statement, followed by a pause, is a preface to a frank remark. It says the speaker is going to give it to you straight, no beating around the bush.

Comment: Worth noting that we also say "look" when we really do want the person to look, as in, "Look!  There's an owl in the tree".  And we also sometimes say "listen" in the situations described in the question, as in, "Listen, I wanted to tell you..."

Comment: '*Mira*' and 'look' also mean ***see***  as in **understand**. Do you see it – do you *get* it?

Comment: I have a high usage of saying "look" when I mean listen, and I most recently was told this on the phone in Spanish as she slowly repeated back the appointment information. To @Robusto's point, this usage may be more of a cultural (not literal) context of conversational speaking.

Comment: *Look* means to see *and* take it in (=face it), just as *listen* means to hear and take it in (=hearken or obey).

Comment: It's also common to say *listen*. Sometimes one says *listen here* or *see here.*  They all mean *pay attention*. They may call attention to something you are presenting on a blackboard as well as to spoken words.

Comment: Interesting question. In my American English, I think of it as an elliptical version of ***Look at it this way:...***. So: ***Look at it this way, I can either break your legs or shoot you*** equals ***Look, I can either break your legs or shoot you***.

Comment: Look, an answer!

Comment: [The Latin word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/video#Latin) *video, videre* which generally means "see" also means observe, understand, consider. This usage is older than the English language. The French verb [voir](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/voir) has many of the same senses.

Comment: It's a spoken discourse marker and emphasizer.  And it can be used quite offhandedly. Maybe it dates back to cave times when the man brought the dead animal to the cave and pointed at it. Later, it was replaced by Look to refer to what is being said. And just in case someone takes the cave man part seriously, it was a joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look (and listen) can be used to mean pay attention in its idiomatic usage.

This specific usage has been documented for thousands of years by the [OED](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/02/look-2.html).

As commenters have pointed out, *look* [[Oxford Learner's Dictionaries]](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/look_1?q=look) has multiple meanings:

> Look - to use your eyes; search; pay attention; appear/seem; face

Comment: Yes. I'd judge that _look_ in "Now look here, young man! ...!" (also suggested by your OED reference) is even more fully semantically bleached.